# Is there a way to eval a stringified JSON object that contains control characters?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a toolbox extension for an online Javascript game. In order to affect the game, my extension generates a command as a string and passes it to an injected script which evals the contents. I'm running into an issue where I can't find the right combination of escape characters and format strings to be able to pass an object which contains a string including control characters to be evald.
An example that works:

```
ObjectToPass = {a:"test"}
ObjectStringified = JSON.stringify(ObjectToPass) // '{"a":"test"}'
StringToPass = `Destination = JSON.parse('${ObjectStringified}')`
// Pass string from popup to main page
// In main page context
eval(StringToPass) // Destination is now {a:"test"}
```

If the attribute has a control character in it, the parsing gets broken.
Per the example above

```
ObjectToPass = {a:"test\n"}
ObjectStringified = JSON.stringify(ObjectToPass) // '{"a":"test\\n"}'
StringToPass = `Destination = JSON.parse('${ObjectStringified}')`
// Pass string from popup to main page
// In main page context
eval(StringToPass) // Expected: Destination is now {a:"test\n"} Actual : Uncaught SyntaxError: Bad control character in string literal in JSON at position 10
```

I've tried every combination of additional escape characters and double stringify/parses that I can think of.

```
eval(`JSON.parse('{"a":"\\n"}')`)
VM8589:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at \<anonymous\>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM8588:1
eval(`JSON.parse('{"a":"\\n"}')`)
VM8605:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Bad control character in string literal in JSON at position 6
at JSON.parse (\<anonymous\>)
eval @ VM8604:1
(anonymous) @ VM8603:1
eval(`JSON.parse('{"a":"\\\n"}')`)
{a: ''}
eval(`JSON.parse(\`{"a":"\\n"}\`)`)
VM9187:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Bad control character in string literal in JSON at position 6
at JSON.parse (\<anonymous\>)
```

I tried more than just these variations but they all yeilded similar results.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because it's the specification of `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I was able to figure out the string that I need to eval is `\`Destination = JSON.parse('{"a":"test\\\\n"}');\`` But can't figure out a way to only escape \s that are escaping other characters.
Being new to SO would it be correct to open a new topic now that the problem has changed?

Comment: Simply remove JSON.parse from StringToPass. It should be `StringToPass = 'Destination = ' + ObjectStringified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string has two forms here:

1. literal
2. value

the literal in source code and console, the value is the actual value.

For the json parser to succeed, you must make string actual value like literal. So it's correct that  `JSON.stringify({a:"test\n"})` return `{"a":"test\\n"}`. but when you pass to eval, it be escaped two times.

`` eval(`JSON.parse('{"a":"\\n"}')`) ``, for argument to the `eval` function in this code, the literal is `JSON.parse('{"a":"\\n"}')`, the value is

```
JSON.parse('{"a":"\n"}')
```

So it's equivalent to execution `JSON.parse('{"a":"\n"}')`.

`JSON.parse('{"a":"\n"}')`, for argument to the `parse` function in this code, the literal is `{"a":"\n"}`, the value is

```
{"a":"
"}
```

So parser will throw error there.

You should replace `"\\n"` with `"\\\\n"` before pass to eval, or you can add extra `\` when you declaration object, like this:

```js
const obj = {a:"test\\n"}
```

But it breaks the original meaning outside of eval

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This didn't quite solve all the issues that I had but got me 90% of the way there. In case anyone else looks at this, the final code I used was `StringToPass = \`Destination = JSON.parse('${ObjectStringified.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')}')\`` in order to properly escape my escapes.

Comment: I still suggest replacing `'\\n'` with `'\\\\n'`, same as other control characters. ` \ ` not only exsit in control characters, may it's a single ` \ `

Comment: While that would absolutely be a more ideal solution, unfortunately I don't have the privilege of knowing the string "test\n" ahead of time. In the case where I am using it, the string "test\n" is a stand in for user generated content.